# Import package from within package directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I'm currently working with the following directory structure:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    MainModule.py
    Module2.py
    run.py
```

Using Python 3, I've learned that in order for `MainModule` to import `Module2`, I need to use an explicit relative import (i.e., `import .Module2`).  However, previously I was testing these files by running `MainModule` as a script, in which case I get

> SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/5031373), I understand that running a module as a script is kind of hackish and unpythonic, according to Guido.  So instead, I've added `run.py`, which is simply:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/package-superdirectory')
from package.MainModule import main

main()
```

For some reason, when I run `run.py`, I'm getting

> ImportError: No module named 'package.MainModule'; 'package' is not a package

Is there a way I can run `MainModule` using a script from within `package/`?  I need the script within the `package/` directory for organizational purposes, and I need `MainModule` to be able to use explicit relative imports.  These files will go in a library, but they are not on `PYTHONPATH` currently, so to my knowledge `python3 -m` won't work here.

#### Update:

I need to run this particular script from a specific directory, `/other/dir`, so the answer needs to be able to run `run.py` (or `MainModule`) from anywhere.

Comment: Tried running `python3 -m package.MainModule` from `/path/to/package-superdirectory`?

Comment: @vaultah see my update; I tried running what you said, but it spit out `No module named package.MainModule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured out how to get this to work.  Since there is a `package` in my environment (it's the stable version of the same package), I had to add the path above `package`'s superdirectory.  So my `run.py` now looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to')
from package-superdirectory.package.MainModule import main

main()
```

Provided all the modules in `package` are using explicit relative imports (i.e. `import .Module2`), calling `./run.py` will run `MainModule` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create 
 **init**.py
 in /package?

Edit: 
Try to use  `from .MainModule import main`

Comment: Yes, but it's empty. Is there something specific that needs to be in it?

Comment: No, it should be empty.